# Count variable in one data.table for each category in a different data.frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

If I have a data.table:

```
  a <- data.table("NAME" = c("A", "B", "A"),  
                  "PASS_FAIL" = c("F", "P", "P"))
```

And a data.frame (which is a frequency table for number of times each unique `NAME` shows up in table `a`:

```
b <- aggregate(data.frame(Count = a$NAME), list(Name = a$NAME), length)
```

So `b` looks like this:

```
> b
  Name Count
1    A     2
2    B     1
```

How do I now add a new column to table b that counts the number of F for each unique NAME? Expected output:

```
> b
  Name    Count    FailCount
1 A       2        1
2 B       1        0
```

I know I need something to the effect of `a$PASS_FAIL == "F"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, grouped by 'NAME', get the count of rows with `.N` and `sum` of the logical expression (`PASS_FAIL == "F"`) for the number of fail cases

```
library(data.table)
a[, .(Count = .N, FailCount = sum(PASS_FAIL=="F")), NAME]
#    NAME Count FailCount
#1:    A     2         1
#2:    B     1         0
```

---

If we need a `base R` method

```
merge(b, aggregate(cbind(FailCount = PASS_FAIL == "F") ~ NAME, a, sum), 
             by.x = 'Name', by.y = 'NAME')
```

Comment: I need to assume a dependency off of table `b` though.. I know that your code generates the full table `b`, however, the way mine works I have to basically use the list of names from `b` and for each name go into table `a` and count the failures.

Comment: @SmallFishinaBigSea  I think by using `aggregate` on the same data and then doing the computation is inefficient

Comment: I think I can use your method if I rewrite some other stuff, my only other question would be how do I control the name of the "NAME" column? With you method, `b` inherits the NAME from `a`.

Comment: @SmallFishinaBigSea  Is it coming from the same dataset?

Comment: `b <- a[, .(Count = .N, FailCount = sum(PASS_FAIL=="F")), NAME]` in this code how would I change `NAME` (coming from `a`) into say "ABC" or something random? Can that be done within the same line of code?

Comment: Just do `.(Name = NAME)]`

Comment: That works for this generic example, and that helped. Unfortunately it isn't working for my large scale scenario... Using Shiny and it is a beast. Mine looks more like: `b <- a[, .(Count = .N, FailCount = sum(PASS_FAIL=="F")), .(Name = input$group_by)]` and I get this error when running that: `The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (1145041).`

Comment: @SmallFishinaBigSea  So, do you want a `base R` solution?

Comment: I guess OP meant that input$group_by is a string containing the column name, in which case `by=c(Name = input$group_by)` should work instead of `.(Name = input$group_by)` ... too bad their account is gone so they cannot reply.

Comment: @Frank It could be the case.  It is strange their account is no longer active

Comment: Turns out the OP has a new account -- eg, linked question in the sidebar

Comment: @Frank that makes sense.  So the old account got removed