# Receiving error when trying to make a frequency table within Shiny app in R

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I am referencing another question on here [Count variable in one data.table for each category in a different data.frame R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200507/count-variable-in-one-data-table-for-each-category-in-a-different-data-frame-r) because I am doing nearly the same thing, except within a shiny app.

I am getting this error: `variable lengths differ (found for 'NAME')` when I try to use this line of code:

```
merge(b, aggregate(cbind(FailCount = PASS_FAIL == "F") ~ NAME, a, sum), 
             by.x = 'Name', by.y = 'NAME')
```

The shiny app will get input `input$stuff` and so in my case this line of code would look like this:

```
merge(b, aggregate(cbind(FailCount = PASS_FAIL == "F") ~ input$stuff, a, sum), 
             by.x = 'Name', by.y = 'input$stuff')
```

I tried getting rid of `by.y = 'input$stuff'` and I still get the error. I am trying to get a frequency table with Name, Count(Frequency), and Count of failures.

Please note the same reproducible example from the referenced link can be used for my question.

Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: If that other question is yours, you can click "flag" and write a note to mods to merge/associate that account into your new one, I guess. Anyway, best to make the question self-contained, in my opinion (ie, include the example data here)... also, this is not reproducible until you provide an example `input` object. `input$stuff` could be anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this works within shiny and with data.tables:

```
b <- a[, .(Count = .N, "Failure Count" = sum(PASS_FAIL == "F")), c(input$stuff)]
names(b)[names(b) == c(input$stuff)] <- "Name"
```

I am not sure if this was due to syntax, data.table requirements, or some weird shiny issue, but this was the only code I could get to run without producing an error within the app and crashing half of my code.